# How to print an array to an input field in jsp?

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, jsp

An array of integers `fibSequence` is passed over to a jsp page `result` using a redirect which is retrieved like this: `<%String[] fibSequence = request.getParameterValues("fibSequence");%>`.
But when I set the input field's value to the fibSequence array I get a memory address of the array and not the integer values stored in the array:

`[Ljava.lang.String;@678f482d`

[image: mem address]

This is how the array is being output to the text box:

`<input type="text" name="fibNum" value="<%=fibSequence%>" size="40px" style="font-size:30pt;height:60px">`

and also I've tried like this from the below answer but the output is still the same:

`<input type="text" name="fibNum" value="<%=java.util.Arrays.deepToString(fibSequence)%>" size="40px" style="font-size:30pt;height:60px">`

Does anyone know how the contents of the array can be output to a textbox in jsp?

I have tried to use the Arrays.toString method to print out the values, but I get an error `Arrays` cannot be resolved:

`<%=Arrays.toString(fibSequence)%>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is work:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>ru.bmstu.FirstFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

FirsFilter.java

```
...
    void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("doFilter from FirstFilter");
        String[] cba = {"1", "2", "3", "5"};
        request.setAttribute("cba", cba);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
...
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Arrays" %>
<html>
<body>
<h3>This is the JBoss example!</h3>
<% String[] abc = {"1", "2", "3"};%>
<%=Arrays.toString(abc)%>
<% String[] cba = (String[]) request.getAttribute("cba"); %>
<%=Arrays.toString(cba)%>
</body>
</html>
```

Result is:

```
This is the JBoss example!
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: In the web.xml when I add the filter declaration, i get a resource not found screen when trying to run the project, any ideas as to why?

Comment: @BrianJ, you create filter (implements javax.servlet.filter)?

Comment: Okay I implemented servlet filter and implemented methods, but the doFilter method is different to yours? See:  `public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1,
   FilterChain arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {`

Comment: @BrianJ, you can use servletresponse and servletrequest similar as httpresponse and httprequest (httpresponse(request) extends of servletresponse(request).

Comment: I tried the above but when the redirect opens the `result` page the cba value printed to the screen is blank. I'll post a question shortly relating to this and link it.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the default `Object.toString()` because array (and array is an Object) doesn't override `toString()`. You could use [`Arrays.toString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object[]%29) like

```
value="<%=java.util.Arrays.toString(fibSequence)%>"
```

Or add the import for `java.util.Arrays` to your JSP.

Comment: I tried the above scriplet code but now I get the output `[[I@2dd8f0aa` Any ideas?

Comment: A multi-dimensional integer array? Use [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object[]%29)

Comment: Nope its a one dimensional array declared like this `private int[]  fibSequence;` Not quite sure why its not printing out the values only the mem address.

Comment: Because that's what `Object.toString()` prints.

Comment: But I tried this code and it still prints the same thing and not the values, `value="<%=java.util.Arrays.toString(fibSequence)%>"`

Comment: You're calling `toString()` on a multidimensional array. Try `int[][] arr = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }; System.out.println(arr);` then try `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));` - I get `[[I@15db9742` for the first (like your example). The first two characters indicate array of array and then the I tells me it's integer.

Comment: I've tried deepToString also but I get the same output `[[I@2dd8f0aa` could it be that the memory address only is being passed over. This is how I'm passing the array to the jsp page: `resp.sendRedirect(("result.jsp?fibSequence=" + fibSequence)); `

Comment: That's `"result.jsp?fibSequence=" + fibSequence.toString())` and that's definitely an `int[][]`

Comment: So why doesn't it print the array values when I use this code? <%=java.util.Arrays.deepToString(fibSequence)%> I've output the contents to the console like this: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fibSequence));` and I get the correct output `[0, 1, 1, 2]` but when I use the above code in the jsp page I get `[[I@23a3469]`

Comment: Because you've already converted it to a string when you called sendRedirect.

Comment: Oh Okay wasn't taking that into account, I'll have a look into that and come back if there is a problem, thanks for your help.